# Using back button after subsequent partial view loads

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net-mvc

I currently have a possibly unorthodox way of direct linking to a parent view with the desired partialview. My parentview renders a partial view depending on a ViewBag variable that is grabbed from the initial request.

```
 public ActionResult Index(Guid clientId, string section)
    {
        if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(section))
        {
            ViewBag.Section = section;
        }

        return View();
    }
```

view

```
<div id="dashboard-container">
@if (ViewBag.Section != null)
{
    switch ((string)ViewBag.Section)
    {
        case "sn-quickview":
            @Html.Partial("_MyQuickView")
            break;
        case "sn-docsfiles":
            break;
        case "sn-needswork":
            @Html.Action("GetNeedsWork", new { clientId = ViewBag.CompanyId})

            break;
        case "sn-advisorynotes":
            @Html.Action("GetAdvisoryNotes", new { companyId = ViewBag.CompanyId })
            break;
        case "sn-documentedrisks":
            break;
        case "sn-expirations":
            @Html.Action("GetDevicesByExpiration", new { clientId = ViewBag.CompanyId})
            break;
        case "sn-lastupdated":
            break;
        case "sn-blankfields":
            break;
    }
}
else
{
    @Html.Partial("_MyQuickView")
}
```

Using this little scheme I can direct link to the Index view with the desired partial view initially loaded. The problem I get is when using the back button. All the back button does is change the url in the address bar to reflect the previous partial view but does not actually show the previous partial view.

**eg** localhost:xxx/Index?section=sn-docsfiles
This url is shown in the browser but the previously rendered partialview does not show. I am using `window.history.pushState` to push the parameterized url to the history in order for the back button to work when these partial views are rendered but it seems it requires a `data` parameter of a json type.

I can see how this would be fairly simple utilizing web api and possibly angular but not with plain old mvc and ajax partials.

**My question is:**
What techniques are there to preserve these previously rendered partials so that they show up correctly when the back button is clicked?

Answer (score 1):

You have the power of MVC routes to return different views, its seems strange that you've chose to do it this way.

Apologies if I haven't understood your question but it seems like what you're trying to achieve is already part of the MVC framework. You have a master view and you're trying to inject child/partial views within it.

If that is what you're trying to do then have look at `@RenderBody()` and MVC Layouts.

Good Article on Layouts - http://www.dotnetcurry.com/ShowArticle.aspx?ID=636

Comment: No I'm aware of partial views and layouts. The issue here is that I'm trying to direct link to a partial view that is returned from an ajax call. When you use Ajax.ActionLink or `$.ajax` you get the returned html without any change in url. So if I have a parent view and I click a link that returns to me some random html data, there is no way I can directly link to that data. If I direct link to it then the browser will only render the partial view without the layout. Does that make any sense?